# Determing Twitter API Rate Limit for Statuses / Filter End-point

Tags: twitter

Currently we are using statuses/filter endpoint to fetch data based on given keywords but the data has been not fetching through out the day and we cannot able to find out exact limit for filter endpoint.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview/statuses-filter

Comment: To who you address this question? To nifi or to twitter?

Comment: twitter @daggett

Comment: then better to remove tags `apache-nifi` and `hortonworks-data-platform`

Answer (score 2):

You are limited to a single streaming connection connection. Limits in Twitter API are usually with regards to rate limits for requests. But that is for non-streaming requests. If your streaming connection gets dropped, you should look at the error code and respond accordingly.

Here is the Twitter doc with codes and streaming message types. 
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview/statuses-filter

When your connection does get dropped, you can try to immediately reconnect but not too frequently. It's recommended that you implement a back-off strategy described here.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/connecting

Also see the section regarding "Stalls."

Comment: In the provided links there is no any exact API request count limit for statuses/filter endpoint @Jonas

Comment: @Manoj That's right. If you want to limit the number of tweets you receive from the stream, you must keep your own count and disconnect from the stream when you are done.

Answer (score 2):

The `statuses/filter` endpoint is limited to 1% of the Twitter firehose so if you require more than this amount of data then it may not provide information.

Comment: Is there any API request count limit for statuses/filter endpoint ?

Comment: no, because you make a single connection and it streams the Tweets. There's no such thing as a rate limit in that case. It's just 1% of the Twitter realtime data. You're limited to a single connection as Jonas said before.